# How can I fix these errors in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-errors

Well this is the code I'm having errors with:

```
this.terminchar = Convert.ToChar(8080);    
List<string> source = new List<string>(this.base64Decode(parse_value).Split(new char[] { this.terminchar }));

if ((source) % 2) == 0)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < source; i++)
  {
    this.keys.Add(source[i], source[++i]);
  }
}
```

I get 3 errors with this code, first one:

> Error  1   Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Second one:

> Error  2   Operator '%' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' and 'int'

Third one:

> Error  3   Invalid expression term '=='

I'm fairly new to C# and this is my friends source code which I'm just looking at to understand the syntax but I have no idea what to do. Any help given would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing some operations on a list. I'm quite sure, you should your lines as follows...

```
if ((source.Count) % 2) == 0)
```

and

```
for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
```

instead

Answer (score 6):

You probably looking for the `.Count` property in both cases.

So use `source.Count`.

Answer (score 1):

obviously, you can use there in for loop. use `i<source.Count`  and also `(source.Count) % 2` instead

Comment: What is `source.Length`? The compiler will tell you.

Comment: sorry, it will contain count as it is List<>

Comment: Still wrong, it is `Count`. Note the uppercase initial character. This aint Java.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the .Count on source to get the count of items in the List

```
List<string> source = new List<string>(this.base64Decode(parse_value).Split(new    char[] { Convert.ToChar(8080) }));
string Command = source[0];
source.RemoveAt(0);
if ((source.Count) % 2) == 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        this.keys.Add(source[i], source[++i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `List` doesn't have `.size()` in C#

Answer (score 0):

`source` is `List<string>` - a container for strings, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx).

Operators `<` and `%` can be applied to int. So your code is missing something.